# Excel Chart Include Future Data?

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I have a chart in Excel that keeps track of the performance of my site's SEO, but I'm not exactly sure how to get my chart to update automatically as I input new data into excel. I have to manually go in and modify the series selection of what the chart takes into consideration.

Is there a way to get the chart to include automatically data in the series that I add to my Excel sheet in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to define a Table, this can be achieved using `Dynamic Named Ranges`. Basically, you create a Defined Name (`Date` and `Sales` in the following) using the Formulas tab, Name Manager (or Define Name), and modify the SERIES formula of the chart to make use of these Defined Names.

The process is outlined in the following screenshot, with the Defined Name `Date` defined as:

```
=OFFSET('Update automatically'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Update automatically'!$A:$A)-1)
```

`Sales` is defined in the same way (A changed to B).

The SERIES formula is:

```
=SERIES(,'Excel Charts.xls'!Date,'Excel Charts.xls'!Sales,1)
```

[image]

If you need more examples, or tutorials, for this you might search "Excel dynamic named range". ozgrid, cpearson, peltiertech (specifically for charts) likely cover this topic well.

[Here is](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183446) a useful guide from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks! After I create the table, how do I make the ranges dynamic (if I were to store the data as a table)?

Comment: If you are referring to MBK's advice (Insert, Table) then, having defined the table, and created a Chart, the chart should automatically update (I believe) as rows are added. (Well, I'm not sure if this happens if you just Paste rows underneath.) If you are referring to my outline then there is a MSDN tutorial at the bottom that should guide you through the process.

Answer (score 2):

Store the data as a table (insert -> table) and base your charts on that table.

Comment: Thanks! After I create the table, how do I make the ranges dynamic?